# `__call` doesn't work in my Lua code

Tags: lua, lua-table

I think a simple dummy example file explains more than long words

```
t = {}
t.__call = print
t.__call(1)
t(2)
```

According to the [documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.4), since `t` is a table, a call to `t`, like `t(2)`, should be redirected to a call to `t.__call`, like `t.__call(2)`.  `t.__call` works fine, no problem, but the "syntaxic sugar" doesn't.  Here is the output of the above code :

```
1
lua: test.lua:4: attempt to call global 't' (a table value)
stack traceback:
        test.lua:4: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

What am I missing ?  Why isn't `t(2)` converted to `t.__call(2)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__call` is a metamethod and should be set on a *table`s metatable*, not the table itself.

```
t = {}
m = {}
m.__call = print

setmetatable(t, m)

t(2)
```

[Check it out here.](http://repl.it/5kO) See @Deduplicator excellent comment for a much more concise way of doing the same thing.

Comment: Or much shorter: `t = setmetatable({}, {__call = print})`